# Java deploy to Heroku with maven plugin invalid credentials

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Java app into Heroku server with maven heroku plugin. But i am getting such error:

```
Failed to execute goal com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:3.0.4:deploy (default-cli) on project endlessblow-server: Execution default-cli of goal com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:3.0.4:deploy failed: Failed to create source statuscode:401 responseBody:{"id":"unauthorized","message":"Invalid credentials provided."}
```

my pom.xml looks like this:

```
(...)

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>MY_APP</appName>
                    <processTypes>
                        <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* pl.jawegiel.Main</web>
                    </processTypes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

(...)
```

How to solve that? A few weeks earlier everything was working fine.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By authenticating. The unauthorized message is pretty clear. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication

Answer (score 0):

From the Maven plugin's doc: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-maven-plugin#heroku-api-key

> This plugin uses Heroku's Platform API and thus requires an API key to function. If you have the Heroku CLI installed and logged in with heroku login, the plugin will automatically pick up your API key. Alternatively, you can use the HEROKU_API_KEY environment variable to set your API key

I guess you were previously logged in with Heroku CLI, so running mvn heroku:deploy was working just fine...